# dplyr::select semantics for across(), select columns in range a:n but then exclude in a oner

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's a data frame:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  blah = letters[1:10],
  x = rnorm(10),
  x_st = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10),
  y_st = rnorm(10),
  z = rnorm(10),
  z_st = rnorm(10)
)
```

I would like to mutate x,y and z only to be their squares. Something similar to:

```
# want square just x,y,z
mydf %>% mutate(across(x:z_st, ~ .x^2))
```

Except that here all columns between x and z_st are included. I want to tell r in english 'mutate all columns between x and z_st but ignore any containing string _st'.

I'm wondering if there's a elegant one liner as opposed to making two select calls along the lines. I.e. I want to avoid something similar to this `mydf %>% select(x:z_st) %>% select_at(vars(!matches('_st')))` i.e. want to minimize my code to write one less pipe command if at all possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column names are not in a range (`:`), then use `c` with unquoted/quoted column names

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
   mutate(across(c(x, y, z), ~ .x^2))
```

---

Or specify a regex pattern in `matches` to only select columns that have names 'x', 'y', z' by prefixing `^` (at the start) and suffix (`$`) at the end of the string

```
mydf %>% 
   mutate(across(matches('^[xyz]$'), ~ .^2))
```

---

Or yet another option is using `-` to remove those columns that `matches` the '_st' from the range `x:z_st`

```
mydf %>%
    mutate(across(c(x:z_st, -matches('_st')), ~ .^2))
```

Comment: This is great thanks. Out of curiosity suppose I was working with a range `x:z_st`, is there a way to apply a filter/regex rule to that range within the same command? i.e "select(x:zt) except if matches string _st"? I guess no but wanted to ask

Comment: @user14328853 updted the post